# BLAS should automatically detected by CMake-GUI 3.10.1

Tags: c++, blas, cmake-gui

I have a project running via `CMake-GUI 3.10.1` with `MinGW` ,But When I try to configure that I got this error.I think something wrong with my `CMake-GUI`.Maybe `BLAS` should automatically detected by `CMake-GUI`.So what should I do.

```
The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
The C compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/gfortran.exe
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/gfortran.exe  -- works
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
Checking whether C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/gfortran.exe supports Fortran 90
Checking whether C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/gfortran.exe supports Fortran 90 -- yes
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/g++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:49 (CMAKE_POLICY):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0022 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


Checking whether GFortran version >= 4.8 -- yes
Found MPI_C: C:/Windows/System32/msmpi.dll  
Found MPI_CXX: C:/Windows/System32/msmpi.dll  
Found MPI_Fortran: C:/Windows/System32/msmpi.dll  
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - found
Looking for pthread_create
Looking for pthread_create - found
Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:699 (message):
  A required library with BLAS API not found.  Please specify library
  location.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:151 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "F:/FreshElmerCM10MGW_ouput_x02/elmerfem/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: ***Maybe BLAS should automatically detected by CMake-GUI*** Package detection in windows needs some user intervention at times because in windows there is no defined place to install libraries and header files.

Comment: Findblas.cmake is in the cmake directories.but there is no blas files in cmake directory. Maybe use previous versions.or any way to install blas and lapack packages without struggling with codes.

Comment: I want to know where is the directory for blas and which file is for blas?so after that how could I introduce them to cmake file?

Comment: I found  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748767/find-blas-include-directory-with-cmake   near to my answer .I want to be sure the correct way before start processing on that.

Comment: As https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindBLAS.html you could see blas is an installed package via cmake.

Comment: I found my answer at http://www.elmerfem.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3725. But working with its internal link. http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries_mingw  Is complicated and confusing. Would some body simplify them