# Use cmake FindBLAS to link OpenBLAS

Tags: cmake, blas, openblas

I am using `cmake 3.16`, and I know that cmake supports finding `OpenBLAS` by using `FindBLAS` [(here)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindBLAS.html?highlight=findblas).

I am trying to link `OpenBLAS` to my c++ project. Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(my_project)

# source file
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

# executable file
add_executable(main.exe ${SOURCES})

# link openblas
set(BLA_VENDER OpenBLAS)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
if(BLAS_FOUND)
    message("OpenBLAS found.")
    include_directories(${BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(main.exe ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})
endif(BLAS_FOUND)
```

If I run `cmake`, it runs just find, and outputs `OpenBLAS found.`. However, if I start to compile the codes (`make VERBOSE=1`), the library is not linked, so that the codes fail to compile. Here is the error info:

```
fatal error: cblas.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cblas.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I installed OpenBLAS successfully. The header files are in `/opt/OpenBLAS/include`, and the shared libraries are in `/opt/OpenBLAS/lib`. My OS is ubuntu 18.04.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: Description "so that the codes fail to compile" is not helpful. Please, provide **exact** error message you got. Also, using `message()` command you may print values of variables which you use (`BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `BLAS_LIBRARIES`). BTW, the first variable - `BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS` - is not noted in the documentation you refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Tsyvarev. I found the problem.

I tried to use `message()` to print out the variables.

```
message(${BLAS_LIBRARIES})
```

Which gives:

```
/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so
```

So the shared library is found.

However, for `BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS`, it gives:

```
message(${BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (message):
  message called with incorrect number of arguments
```

It turns out that `BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS` is not in the `FindBLAS` variables. So I add the include header files manually:

```
set(BLA_VENDER OpenBLAS)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
if(BLAS_FOUND)
    message("OpenBLAS found.")
    include_directories(/opt/OpenBLAS/include/)
    target_link_libraries(main.exe ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})
endif(BLAS_FOUND)
```

This time it compiles without error. Instead of using `include_directories()`, you could also try `find_path()` ([check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770787/11025985)).